# Is documents loaded to div, stay in memory after I load another?

Tags: jquery

1. I have `DIV` with `id="popupWindow"`. I'm loading `doc1.html` doc that contains Javascript  code to this `DIV`.
   My question is if I will load another document into `popupWindow` after, will java scripts from past document still be in memory?
2. And if I will be loading doc1.html several times, will those script be doubled/tripled in memory, causing huge memory leaks?
3. Should I just load scripts seperatly aside from html doc, or is it ok to have JS in this `doc1.html`?

Edit:
Programing version of question:
1. If I use $("#id").load("somedoc.html"). Scripts from somedoc.html will be loaded. Then if I will use $("#id").load("somedoc.html2"). Will scripts from somedoc.html disapear from memory, like DOM elements?
2. If it will remain, so if i will load somedoc.html many times after will it junk memory?

Comment: If you wanted to have a script that can run/execute within different `.html` documents, then you should just separate the script from the document, and just embed it into the page. By that way, you can carry on the scripts from a `.html` document to another. **NOTE:** This is if I didn't misunderstand your post.

Comment: If I use $("#id").load("somedoc.html"). Scripts from somedoc.html will be loaded. Then if I will use $("#id").load("somedoc.html2"). Will scripts from somedoc.html disapear from memory, like DOM elements?